# Finding and replacing values in a list based on fuzzy matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to cycle through the values of a column in pandas and change all similar values so they are harmonised. I have first extracted the column as a list and want to loop through for each row, replace the similar value when found with the value which is similar, then place the list back into dataframe replacing the column. so for example a column like:

```
Cool
Awesome
cool
CoOl
Awesum
Awesome
Mathss
Math
Maths
Mathss
```

would become:

```
CoOl
Awesome
coOol
CoOl
Awesome
Awesome
Mathss
Mathss
Mathss
Mathss
```

The code is as follows:

```
def matchbrands():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/XXX/db.sqlite3')
    c = conn.cursor()
    matchbrands_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from removeduplicates", conn)

    brands = [x for x in matchbrands_df['brand']]

    i=1

    for x in brands:
        if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, brands[i]) > 85:
            x = brands[i]
        else:
            i += 1

    n = matchbrands_df.columns[7]
    matchbrands_df.drop(n, axis=1, inplace=True)
    matchbrands_df[n] = brands

    matchbrands_df.to_csv('/Users/XXX/matchedbrands.csv')
    matchbrands_df.to_sql('removeduplicates', conn, if_exists="replace")
```

however this does not change the column at all. I am unsure why. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your code above should be a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to check what you have in variables. Asigning `x = ...` doesn't change original value in `brands` - you would have to work with indexes and do `brand[index] = brands[i]`. All this `for`-loop seems strange and I don't trust if it really do what you want. You should use `print()` in this `for`-loop to check what it does. As for me it may need second `for`-loop to do it correctly but I don't know how works `fuzz.token_sort_ratio`. And maybe it could be done with .apply instead of converting column to list.

Comment: shorter: `brands = matchbrands_df['brand'].to_list()` or `brands = list(matchbrands_df['brand'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense.

First: using `x =...` you can't change value on list `brands`. You need `brands[index] = ...`

Second: it needs nested `for`-loop to compare `x` with all other words in `brands`

```
for index, word in enumerate(brands):
    for other in brands[index+1:]:
        #print(word, other, fuzz.token_sort_ratio(word, other))
        if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(word, other) > 85:
            brands[index] = other
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd
import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz as fuzz

data = {'brands':
'''Cool
Awesome
cool
CoOl
Awesum
Awesome
Mathss
Math
Maths
Mathss'''.split('\n')
}  # rows

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('--- before ---')
print(df)

brands = df['brands'].to_list()

print('--- changes ---')
for index, word in enumerate(brands):
    #for other_index, other_word in enumerate(brands):
    for other_index, other_word in enumerate(brands[index+1:], index+1):
        #if word != other_word:
            result = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(word, other_word)
            
            if result > 85:
                print(f'OK | {result:3} | {index:2} {word:7} -> {other_index:2} {other_word}')                
            elif result > 50:
                print(f'   | {result:3} | {index:2} {word:7} -> {other_index:2} {other_word}')
                
            if result > 85:
                brands[index] = other_word
                #break
                #word = other_word

df['brands'] = brands

print('--- after ---')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---
    brands
0     Cool
1  Awesome
2     cool
3     CoOl
4   Awesum
5  Awesome
6   Mathss
7     Math
8    Maths
9   Mathss
--- changes ---
OK | 100 |  0 Cool    ->  2 cool
OK | 100 |  0 Cool    ->  3 CoOl
   |  77 |  1 Awesome ->  4 Awesum
OK | 100 |  1 Awesome ->  5 Awesome
OK | 100 |  2 cool    ->  3 CoOl
   |  77 |  4 Awesum  ->  5 Awesome
   |  80 |  6 Mathss  ->  7 Math
OK |  91 |  6 Mathss  ->  8 Maths
OK | 100 |  6 Mathss  ->  9 Mathss
OK |  89 |  7 Math    ->  8 Maths
   |  80 |  7 Math    ->  9 Mathss
OK |  91 |  8 Maths   ->  9 Mathss
--- after ---
    brands
0     CoOl
1  Awesome
2     CoOl
3     CoOl
4   Awesum
5  Awesome
6   Mathss
7    Maths
8   Mathss
9   Mathss
```

It doesn't change `Awesum` into `Awesome` because it gets `77`

It doesn't change `Math` into `Mathss` because it gets `80`. But it gets `89` for `Maths`.

If you use `word = other_word` in `for`-loop then it can convert `Math` to `Maths` (`89`) and next this `Maths` to `Mathss` (`91`). But this way it may change many times and finally it change to word which originally can gives value much smaller then `85`. Expected result you can get also for `75` instead of `85`.

But this method get last word with value `>85`, not with the bigest value - so there can be better matching word and it will not use it. Using break it get first word with `>85`. maybe it should get all words with `>85` and choose word with biggest value. And it would have to skip words which are the same but in different row. But all this can make strange situations.

In comments in code I keep other ideas for modifications.

---

**EDIT:**

The same with `>75` and with colors.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz as fuzz
from colorama import Fore as FG, Back as BG, Style as ST

data = {'brands':
'''Cool
Awesome
cool
CoOl
Awesum
Awesome
Mathss
Math
Maths
Mathss'''.split('\n')
}  # rows

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('--- before ---')
print(df)

brands = df['brands'].to_list()

print('--- changes ---')
for index, word in enumerate(brands):
    print('-', index, '-')
    #for other_index, other_word in enumerate(brands):
    for other_index, other_word in enumerate(brands[index+1:], index+1):
        #if word != other_word:
            result = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(word, other_word)
            
            if result > 85:
                color = ST.BRIGHT + FG.GREEN
                info  = 'OK'
            elif result > 75:
                color = ST.BRIGHT + FG.YELLOW
                info  = ' ?'
            elif result > 50:
                color = ST.BRIGHT + FG.WHITE
                info  = '  '
            else:
                color = ST.BRIGHT + FG.RED
                info  = ' -'
            
            print(f'{color}{info} | {result:3} | {index:2} {word:7} -> {other_index:2} {other_word}{ST.RESET_ALL}')
                
            if result > 75:
                brands[index] = other_word
                #break
                #word = other_word
    
df['brands'] = brands

print('--- after ---')
print(df)
```

Comment: I was thinking to use `df.apply(func)` but this would reduce only outer `for`-loop` and it would still need inner `for`-loop `for other_index, other_word` inside `func`

Comment: BTW: I little changed code which sets colors. And added `print('-')`.

Comment: Hi @furas, would you help me here?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70051704/6907424 Thanks.